# Sorting HTTP get data in Angular 7

Tags: angular

I would like to have the http get results sorted in Angular 7.

A solution provided on the site used `map` to `in` combination with converting the response object to the destination type and getting back the `json`, but it seems to apply to an older version of Angular while I am using Angular 7.

```
public getAlertKeys (): Observable<AlertMsg[]> {
    return this.http.get<AlertMsg[]>(this.alertsUrl);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code, how the `AlertMsg` object would look like?

Comment: post some sample data, how the data would like in the response and based on which element you would want to sort.

Comment: Can you elaborate bit more perhaps Expected O/P, `Http Module` is Deprecated and `HttpClientModule` assumes the response to be of type `json` and implicitly parses it,`map` operator is used to compose new Observable and it would still work if you wanna modify the response or sort it

Comment: Is the observable payload only used in the template? Use a `pipe`.  Otherwise, sort the array in the subscribe callback using vanilla Typescript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use the RxJS `map` operator and the `sort` function which is available on JavaScript arrays. Bear in mind that the function provided to `sort` needs to return a number (negative, zero or positive) to indicate the correct order.

Given you have the following `AlertMessage` model:

```
export class AlertMessage {
    text: string;
    priority: number;
}
```

When you want to sort by priority which is of type `number`, then you can use the following

```
return this.http.get<AlertMessage[]>(this.alertsUrl).pipe(
    map(messages => messages.sort((a1: AlertMessage, a2: AlertMessage) => a1.priority - a2.priority ))
);
```

When you want to sort by text which is of type `string`, then you can use the following

```
return this.http.get<AlertMessage[]>(this.alertsUrl).pipe(
    map(messages => messages.sort((a1: AlertMessage, a2: AlertMessage) => {
        if(a1.text < a2.text) return -1;
        if(a1.text > a2.text) return 1;
        return 0;
    }))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using something like this:

```js
public getAlertKeys (): Observable<AlertMsg[]> {
  return this.http.get<AlertMsg[]>(this.alertsUrl)
  .pipe(
    map((res:AlertMsg[]) => res.sort((a: AlertMsg, b: AlertMsg) => compareFn(a.keyToCompare, b.keyToCompare))
  );
}
```

With `compareFn` being the way you want to compare your objects (e.g `a.key.localeCompare(b.key)` for strings, `a.key - b.key` for numbers...)